# Cassandra ERROR: LEAK DETECTED

Tags: mysql, cassandra, cqlsh

I am having a two node Cassandra cluster( Version : 3.10).
I tried to read data from SQL and write into Cassandra. Everything was Ok, but at some point I got this error -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.22.231:9042] Connection has been closed
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException.copy(TransportException.java:38)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException.copy(TransportException.java:24)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:43)
        at TableCreator.insertDataToCassandra(TableCreator.java:1037)
        at TableCreator.createTable(TableCreator.java:356)
        at DbMigration.main(DbMigration.java:25)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.22.231:9042] Connection has been closed
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ConnectionCloseFuture.force(Connection.java:1215)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ConnectionCloseFuture.force(Connection.java:1200)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.defunct(Connection.java:450)
```

Nodetool status shows both the nodes are UP and healthy -

```
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.22.229  77.39 GiB  256          100.0%            335fc3a2-c21f-44ad-a937-487ba457c2fa  rack1
UN  192.168.22.231  77.39 GiB  256          100.0%            a5eaf96c-eaf9-4e2e-bd6b-6186ce944cd0  rack1
```

Now I am not able to connect to my first node -

```
cqlsh --connect-timeout=30 192.168.22.231
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.22.231': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.22.231', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

But I can connect to second server. I tried to check system.log and debug.log
**syatem.log**

> INFO  [CompactionExecutor:4003] 2017-06-19 07:25:19,676
>   NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (1.000GiB), cannot
>   allocate chunk of 1.000MiB INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-06-19
>   07:28:02,222 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:75 - Redistributing index
>   summaries INFO  [CompactionExecutor:4009] 2017-06-19 07:40:42,023
>   NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (1.000GiB), cannot
>   allocate chunk of 1.000MiB INFO  [CompactionExecutor:4015] 2017-06-19
>   07:56:04,582 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached
>   (1.000GiB), cannot allocate chunk of 1.000MiB INFO 
>   [CompactionExecutor:4021] 2017-06-19 08:11:26,674 NoSpamLogger.java:91
>   - Maximum memory usage reached (1.000GiB), cannot allocate chunk of 1.000MiB INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-06-19 08:21:48,726 GCInspector.java:284 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 225ms.  CMS Old Gen:
>   5813642680 -> 3194404296; Par Eden Space: 10360904 -> 347594616; Par
>   Survivor Space: 83886080 -> 42514752
>
> INFO  [CompactionExecutor:4027] 2017-06-19 08:26:49,414
>   NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (1.000GiB), cannot
>   allocate chunk of 1.000MiB INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-06-19
>   08:28:02,341 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:75 - Redistributing index
>   summaries INFO  [CompactionExecutor:4031] 2017-06-19 08:42:12,733
>   NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (1.000GiB), cannot
>   allocate chunk of 1.000MiB INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-06-19
>   08:52:33,145 GCInspector.java:284 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 215ms. 
>   CMS Old Gen: 5868761104 -> 3186639968; Par Eden Space: 9853592 ->
>   423279080; Par Survivor Space: 83886080 -> 45608368
>
> INFO  [CompactionExecutor:4037] 2017-06-19 08:57:34,632
>   NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (1.000GiB), cannot
>   allocate chunk of 1.000MiB

**Debug.log**

> DEBUG [SlabPoolCleaner] 2017-06-19 09:12:59,260
>   ColumnFamilyStore.java:899 - Enqueuing flush of size_estimates:
>   78.229MiB (4%) on-heap, 0.000KiB (0%) off-heap DEBUG [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:6285] 2017-06-19 09:12:59,575
>   Memtable.java:461 - Writing
>   Memtable-size_estimates@1285230058(21.550MiB serialized bytes, 150876
>   ops, 4%/0% of on/off-heap limit), flushed range =
>   (min(-9223372036854775808), max(9223372036854775807)]
>
> DEBUG [MemtableFlushWriter:6230] 2017-06-19 09:12:59,618
>   ColumnFamilyStore.java:1197 - Flushed to
>   [BigTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-21460-big-Data.db')]
>   (1 sstables, 2.340MiB), biggest 2.340MiB, smallest 2.340MiB
>
> DEBUG [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:6285] 2017-06-19 09:12:59,895
>   Memtable.java:490 - Completed flushing
>   /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-21461-big-Data.db
>   (15.813MiB) for commitlog position
>   CommitLogPosition(segmentId=1496885272130, position=32411980)
>
> DEBUG [MemtableFlushWriter:6231] 2017-06-19 09:13:00,077
>   ColumnFamilyStore.java:1197 - Flushed to
>   [BigTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-21461-big-Data.db')]
>   (1 sstables, 2.340MiB), biggest 2.340MiB, smallest 2.340MiB
>
> DEBUG [CompactionExecutor:4043] 2017-06-19 09:13:02,440
>   CompactionTask.java:255 - Compacted
>   (0b5956b0-5484-11e7-b5a8-01c062b805b9) 4 sstables to
>   [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-21458-big,]
>   to level=0.  20.780MiB to 13.916MiB (~66% of original) in 6,349ms. 
>   Read Throughput = 3.273MiB/s, Write Throughput = 2.192MiB/s, Row
>   Throughput = ~131,062/s.  12 total partitions merged to 5.  Partition
>   merge counts were {2:4, 4:1, }
>
> DEBUG [CompactionExecutor:4043] 2017-06-19 09:13:02,440
>   CompactionTask.java:155 - Compacting
>   (0f221e81-5484-11e7-b5a8-01c062b805b9)
>   [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-21461-big-Data.db:level=0,
>   /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-21460-big-Data.db:level=0,
>   /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-21459-big-Data.db:level=0,
>   /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-21458-big-Data.db:level=0,
>   ]
>
> DEBUG [CompactionExecutor:4043] 2017-06-19 09:13:08,453
>   CompactionTask.java:255 - Compacted
>   (0f221e81-5484-11e7-b5a8-01c062b805b9) 4 sstables to
>   [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-21462-big,]
>   to level=0.  20.775MiB to 13.923MiB (~67% of original) in 6,012ms. 
>   Read Throughput = 3.455MiB/s, Write Throughput = 2.316MiB/s, Row
>   Throughput = ~131,059/s.  8 total partitions merged to 5.  Partition
>   merge counts were {1:4, 4:1, }

Any suggestion will be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran out of memory (first line of your log). Strange enough this is an info and not a warning. When you are out of memory the system might still be healthy but just not able to accept any new connections. Add more memory until you have enough to run stable.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I changed file_cache_size_in_mb from 1024 to 2048 and restarted Cassandra, restart log pointed " SSTable.. Too many open files", I tried to manage it by incressing the no of open file descriptor using command ulimit -n 100000.